# Android + nutiteq: offline map tiles not shown

Tags: android, android-mapview, cartodb, nutiteq

Referring to [this](https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d/wiki/Offline-map-tiles) site, I built my `MapActivity` as following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        mapView.setComponents(new Components());

        RasterDataSource datasource = new PackagedRasterDataSource(new EPSG3857(), 11, 12, "t{zoom}_{x}_{y}", getApplicationContext());
        RasterLayer mapLayer = new RasterLayer(datasource, 16);
        mapView.getLayers().setBaseLayer(mapLayer);
        mapView.setFocusPoint(mapView.getLayers().getBaseLayer().getProjection().fromWgs84(47.0f, 9.0f));
        //mapView.setZoom(15);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mapView.startMapping();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        mapView.stopMapping();
        super.onStop();
    }

}
```

I have put tiles in my `res/raw` folder, but however nothing is shown. Is there anything I am missing? According to the tutorial, it must show something. What else could I provide to debug it? The xml is a simple `MapView` with `width` and `height`.

The tiles are generated [here](http://www.mapcacher.com/) and [here](http://dev.nutiteq.ee/jarmaps/). As parameters I set no CloudMade Key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things to check:

1. Your `new PackagedRasterDataSource(new EPSG3857(), 11, 12 ...` defines that the data is for zoom levels 11-12, so you should have "t11_x_y.png" etc, with proper x and y, in your tile set, and map zoomed and centered to area covered with tiles.
2. Method `fromWgs84(47.0f, 9.0f)` should have order longitude (x, easting), latitude (y, northing). Make sure this is correct.

Comment: I have tried the above.. My map still doesn't show up.. Any clues? And what do you mean by "centered to area covered with tiles"

Comment: I would need to see your project (at least tiles). Most probably you zoom and center map to location where there is no map (are no tiles).